# How to play songs from list. I am able to get the songs but I am not able to play any of the contents

Tags: android

Here is my code below for getting songs from device. but I am not able to play any of the contents.

```
try {
     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
     MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

     if (cursor == null) {
        // Query failed...
     } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     // Nothing to query. There is no music on the device.
     }else {
     // add each song to mItems.

    //these is the part that gets each item from the cursor and adds them to the list.

     do {
          int artistColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
          // add each song to mItems.
         int titleColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
          // add each song to mItems.
          int albumColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
          // add each song to mItems.
          int albumArt = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
          // add each song to mItems.
          int durationColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
          // add each song to mItems.
          int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
          // add each song to mItems.
          int filePathIndex =  cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

          int art = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART);

          // these section adds the media info(MediaInfo.class) to the mediaList.
          MediaFileInfo audio = new MediaFileInfo();
          audio.setFileName(cursor.getString(titleColumn));
          audio.setFilePath(cursor.getString(filePathIndex));
          audio.setImgId(cursor.getInt(albumArt));
          audio.setFileType(type);
          audio.setImgId(cursor.getInt(art));

           //am adding all the items to the list(medaiList).

          mediaList.add(audio);
     } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: you need to read `MediaPlayer` API documentation

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set datasource of your cursor path means your song path.And If you are using Content provider, URI query, `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`.

Then you have to set your returned cursor in your song path cursor. Like this,

```
String path = cursor.getString(getColumnIndex(Audio.Media.DATA));
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(path);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

It will help you...

Comment: if it is works for you then accept as an answer...thanks